# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, frameworks, firebase-analytics

I am trying to Call Firebase Analytics in my iOS app ,i am getting error while compiling project .

I have created one framework and from that framework calling firebase analytics but I don’t understand getting below error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Showing Recent Errors Only
:-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics
```

Below is my app structure

- iOS App

  - MyCustom Framework

    - Viewcontroller

Comment: I've seen this before. The only workaround that worked for us was to link Firebase to the main target instead of the framework

Comment: yes, i have linked firebase to main target

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when added Firebase using Carthage.

So after running a command 
*carthage update --platform iOS* 
you need to copy files from Carthage/Build/iOS/ into your project
Actually it just copied references to Firebase files, but files were still in Carthage/Build/iOS/ folder

After updating of Xcode and therefore Swift - I needed to update my dependencies - and after that, I got such an error

The reason was that after update an additional **PromisesObjC.framework** was introduced, and it, of course, was not included in the project.

So the complete removal of all Firebase-related frameworks and adding them again - fixed the problem.

P.S. and don't forget to delete Firebase.framework from the Link Binary With Libraries Build Phase in Xcode not to run in another error after update :) 
[Error: Firebase.framework does not contain bitcode.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/911#issuecomment-372455235)

Comment: If using cocoapods like myself, comment out firebase installs in the Podfile, run pod update, uncomment Firebase modules, run pod install, and it should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you import the `PromisesObjc.framework` after deleting your old Firebase libraries. I tried all the other steps but this one was also required.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was solved by updating the 'tag' in the following line in `ios/Podfile` to the most recent tag (based on the github repository):

`pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.1.0'`